# nsIXULWindow vs nsIDOMWindow

Tags: dom, firefox-addon, listener, xul

I was wondering the differences between nsIDOMWindow (returned by Services.wm.getWindowEnumerator and nsIXULWindow returned by Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator.

The reason I ask is because i heavily use the windowListener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIWindowMediator#addListener%28%29)

I created an example on MDN but don't understand the difference between the two windows. I was thinking if I do i can make a better example.
Thanks

Comment: ++! I personally would like to see some sort of diagram which explains the roles that each interface plays, and how to either cast (`QueryInterface`) or navigate (e.g: `nsIDocShellTreeItem`) to other 'level's of the XUL interface. I guess most mozilla platform devs gain familiarity with the layout through experience... I certainly haven't seen good documentation on MDN about the relationships between the interfaces. I even tried to build a diagram mechanically from the docs using `supports` and mentions of `nsI`* in methods/attributes, but it ends up being so self-referential it's unreadable.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh much thanks for that comment and idea. I would really super appreciate something like that too. I would finally learn how to use QueryInterface, as the answer to your comment would answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629192/some-words-on-queryinterface-magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIXULWindow is a XUL Application Object Model(AOM) window:

```
#document
  window                 main-window
    ...
      browser
        #document
          window         myExtensionWindow
```

> Just as HTML is reflected in the DOM as nodes like `link`, `layer`, and `img`, XUL is reflected in the Application Object Model in the hierarchy of XUL widgets: `browser`, `menu`, `menuitem`, and so on. The DOM and the AOM form a kind of continuum, the whole of which is manipulable from the standards upon which XUL is based.

NSIDOMWindow is a HTML Document Object Model(DOM) window:

> When a XUL window contains a widget capable of displaying a page, such as `<browser>` or `<iframe>`, the document in that widget is, naturally, separate from the document of the chrome window itself. There also is a Window object for each sub-document, although there's no window in a common sense for the sub-document.
>
> The same holds for chrome windows opened inside a tab of `<tabbrowser>`. The elements above the chrome document opened in the tab are separate from your chrome document.

**References**

- [Working with Windows in Chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)
- [XUL Bestiary: Object Models - DOM and AOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/A_XUL_Bestiary#Object_Models.3A_DOM_and_AOM)
- [XUL Accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/XUL)
- [Inner and Outer Windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Inner_and_outer_windows)

Comment: Super cool, thanks for this. This question gets us into inner and outer window which is explained here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Inner_and_outer_windows