# Some words on QueryInterface magic

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

many times I have had an issue and post for help and so many times QueryInterface is the solution. I have been addon programming for a long time now but never understood QueryInterface. It seems like magic, like it holds the solution to everything.

like:

```
window.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                         .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                         .rootTreeItem
                         .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
```

So my question is I see a QueryInterface chain, I don't get why the chain, and I definitely don't get how to create my own chain. I don't get how do you know to chain from nsiInterfaceRequester to nsiWebNavigation and not from nsiInterfaceRequester straight to nsiDOMWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nothing special here. DOM windows implement the `nsIInterfaceRequestor` interface that allows getting related objects. One such object is the docshell that is associated with the window - you get it by asking for the `nsIWebNavigation` interface but it also implements the `nsIDocShell` and `nsIDocShellTreeItem` interfaces - and `nsIInterfaceRequestor`. The docshell for the current window lets you get to the docshell for the top window, despite the security boundary between chrome and content. And there you can use the `nsIInterfaceRequestor` interface again to ask the docshell for the window associated with it.

You can simply implement the `nsIInterfaceRequestor` interface in your XPCOM component just like any other interface. I don't see any reason to ever do that however, it's an ugly hack to hide internal window-related interfaces from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks so much wlad for this reply I've been wanting one but I started to feel I was the most epxerienced ff guy around here hahah and I was like that that cant be true cuz i suck haha. What I mean by magic is like with QueryInterface is there a way to find the tab another tab was opend from? Like you know tabs are opened relative right, I saw somewhere but can't recall how they did it, it was like magic.

Comment: Also how do you now DOM windows implement ```nsIInterfaceRequestor`? because when i go ```Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log(window);``` and then click on that in the Browser Console and then in VariableViewer filter by nsI I don't see nsIInterfaceRequestor anywhere there image [HERE](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/i20dont20see20nsIInterfaceRequestor_zps7bfc9d43.png)

Comment: @Noitidart: To check whether the window implements `nsIInterfaceRequestor` you do `window instanceof Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor` - this will call `QueryInterface()` implicitly, you cannot check supported interfaces just by looking at the properties of an object. For the entire list of supported interfaces you have to go to the source code.

Comment: Ah I got it, thanks Wlad! But even if doesnt implement this people can do some tricks to make it use QueryInterface right?

Comment: @Noitidart: This is getting into XPCOM basics. Want to read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript) maybe?

Comment: Ah I read docs a lot but never a page on how to build my own XPCOM component, I think it's a good idea as learning from ground up teaches stuff to you. I'll check it out thx Wladimir!